# Rails 3 + MongoDB: How to do a nested query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I am using Ruby Mongo Driver.

```
  @surname = coll2.find("name" => {"surname" => "testing"})
```

Shouldn't this be working? I get no results.

I have  `{"name" : { "surname" : "testing" }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work perfectly.

```
> coll2.insert({"name" => {"surname" => "testing"})
# => BSON::ObjectId('4dcb2e53abad691f62000002')
> coll2.insert({"name" => {"surname" => "another"})
# => BSON::ObjectId('4dcb2e53abad691f62000003')
> coll2.find().count
# => 2
> coll2.find("name" => {"surname" => "testing"}).count
# => 1
> coll2.find("name" => {"surname" => "testing"}).first
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4dcb2e53abad691f62000002'), "name"=>{"surname"=>"testing"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following would work too

```
coll2.find("name.surname"=>"testing").first
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked only with curly brackets. Like that:

```
col2.find({"name.surname": "testing"})
```